# Parse an email with HTML as text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parsing

I am sending text with html tags to my rails server. What I want is to parse the tags as html, but display it as regular text.

```
text = '<p>some text</p>'
```

### Mailer

```
class ContributeTestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def contribute_test_mailer(test)
    @test = test

    mail(to: 'mail', subject: 'subject')
  end
end
```

### Template

```
 <div>
    <%= @text %>
 </div>
```

The result email, as a plain text:

```
<p>some text</p>
```

Comment: Try `<%= raw @text %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
<%= raw @text %>
```

**or**

```
<%== @text %>
```